# Returning the regular expression match as part of a split (or equivalent functionality)

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to parse through some log files and put them into a database for analysis.  A single line looks something like this:

`2012-09-30 17:16:27,213 [39] (boxes) ERROR Assembly.Places [(null)] - Error while displaying a thing`

I have made a regular expression that works well for pulling out the date in front and breaking up the lines that way, but I lose the date itself.  This is a pretty important bit of data, and I don't want to lose it!

I cannot just do this by `\r\n`, because some logs are fatal errors that include stack traces for the developers.  Those, obviously, use `\r\n` to make them readable.

My current code looks like this for reference:

```
var logpath = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\a\directory", "*.log");
foreach (var log in logpath)
{
    var fileStream = new StreamReader(log);
    var fileString = fileStream.ReadToEnd();
    var records = Regex.Split(fileString, "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}");
            ...
}
```

Comment: As date length is constant, substring will serve your purpose?

Comment: Note that `StreamReader` is `IDisposable` and therefore you should work with `using (var fileStream = new StreamReader(log)) { ... }`

Comment: @Tomalak Good call.  I was so absorbed making sure the string was extracted the way I wanted that I forgot that.

Comment: @sgud It will serve just fine, yes!  However as of the time of this posting I had no idea how to get the position at the front of things.  I am now attempting Tomalak's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Split()` will always remove the matched delimiter. The trick is not to match any actual *text*, but rather a *position* in the string.

This is done through [zero-width look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
var datePattern = "^(?=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3})";
var datePositions = new Regex(datePattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

// ...

Regex.Split(fileString, datePositions);
```

Comment: hmm..nice but the OP also need the date I guess

Comment: @Anirudha Yes, but as sgud noted in the comments above, `Substring()` will be enough for that. Plus I suspect that the use of `Split()` indicates that the OP does some subsequent string-handling anyway.

Comment: This worked great!  I wasn't aware this technique existed in the Regex engine before.

Answer (score 0):

You should `match` instead of `splitting`

This is the regex.Use `singleLine` Mode

```
([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3})(.*?)((?=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}|$))
```

Group 1 contains date

Group 2 contains the required date

**NOTE**

The regex is conceptually like this.

```
(yourDate)(.*?yourdata)(?=till the other date|$)
```

Dont forget to use `singlelineMode`

Comment: @YYY the above regex gets both the data(in group2) and the date(in group1) both in diff groups..You dont need to `split`..`Match` it

Comment: @YYY dnt forget to use singleLine Mode

Comment: Alright, I had been afraid of this.  Using something as generic as . (which you have no other choice but to do, since the data is nonstandard) on singleline makes the program match THE ENTIRE REMAINING FILE to the data group.  There are still hundreds or thousands of matches, it's just that only the last match in the file is usable.  Unfortunately this solution as it stands is unusable.

Comment: I was merely making a comment to make this question more informative to anyone who reads it later.  If you have complaints about the question itself I suggest you leave a comment on it.  If your complaint, as I suspect, is more about my conduct, I suggest you report it to the moderators.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not an expert on the subject but I did found this: [Regex.Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match.aspx).

From what I see you can receive the first match of the date format with a [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) object
which has all kind of nice properties that put together you can probably cut the parts you want.

p.s. also exists a Regex.Matches which will return all matches in the file, might be easier for use.

Sorry I don't have time for to find a complete code example.

good day

Comment: My initial idea was to use Match and then Split, then tie the two arrays together.  But that is janky and unreliable, so I'd prefer to not do that.