# Read in a file using a regular expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, streamreader

This is tangentially related to [an earlier question of mine.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939597/returning-the-regular-expression-match-as-part-of-a-split-or-equivalent-functio)

Essentially, the solution in that question worked great, but now I need to adapt it to work in a much larger analysis application.  Simply using `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` is not acceptable, since some of the files I will be reading in are very, very large.  If there's been a mistake and someone forgot to clean up, they can theoretically be gigabytes big.  Obviously I can't just read to the end of that.

Unfortunately, the normal read lines is also not acceptable, because some of the rows of data I am reading in contain stack traces - they obviously use `/r/n` in their formatting.  Ideally, I would like to tell the program to read forward until it hits a match for a regex, which it then returns.  Is there any functionality to do this in .net?  If not, can I get some suggestions for how I'd go about writing it?

Edit: To make it a bit easier to follow my question, here's a paste of some of the important parts of the adapted code:

```
foreach (var fileString in logpath.Select(log => new StreamReader(log)).Select(fileStream => fileStream.ReadToEnd()))
{
    const string junkPattern = @"\[(?<junk>[0-9]*)\] \((?<userid>.{0,32})\)";
    const string severityPattern = @"INFO|ERROR|FATAL";
    const string datePattern = "^(?=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3})";
    var records = Regex.Split(fileString, datePattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
    foreach (var record in records.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) == false))
    ......
```

The problem lies in the Foreach.  `.Select(fileStream => fileStream.ReadToEnd())` is gonna blow up memory badly, I just know it.

Comment: And there you have one of the main reasons I don't really care for using RegEx for tasks like this. If you wrote a simple parser, you could simply adapt it to handle new lines.

Comment: @JonathanWood The regexes are awesome for parsing out individual records after I have the entire record.  I just pop out all the information I need and it goes straight into the associated fields.  The problem is the file input in this case, it seems like it simply isn't flexible enough to give me a single record at a time with the file I've got.  But that seems bogus, doesn't it?  This cannot be an uncommon problem.

Comment: So  a stack trace has /r/n.  Why does that eliminate readline?

Comment: @Blam Readline will feed in on `/r/n`, so if a stack trace goes on for 5 lines, I will get that many incomplete records.  I could work up a ghetto state machine that searches for the `datePattern` that always starts a record, but that just swaps one horrible inefficiency for another.

Comment: I think that collecting ReadLine output into a list until Regex.Match(currentLine, datePattern) returns true sounds like a "good enough" solution

Comment: I think [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282384/how-to-create-a-parserlex-yacc) may help you.

Comment: How is it that a readline forces you to create new record?

Comment: @Blam I will get incomplete/fragmented bits of records on stack traces if I use only ReadLine.  So if I have a stack trace with 5 calls on each different line, I will get most of the record and the call of the stack trace on one call, then the second trace line on the next call, then the third trace line on the next call, etc etc. I can break it around using conditional concatenation and checking with Regex.Match, but that is the ghetto state machine and very inefficient. If that's what I have to do then fine, like Dooh said it might be a 'good enough'. But if I don't have to do that, I won't.

Comment: The stated problem was memory.  ReadLine and StringBuilder are both very efficient.  Only an inefficient state machine if you make it one.

Comment: You need to identify something that you can use as a record separator and chunk the file in a way that won't break your Regex matching. Otherwise, you'll find yourself having to code a Regex enginge that can handle backtracking against a file broken into arbitrary chunks.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509439/multi-line-regex-search-in-whole-file

Comment: @JamieSee if you check my previous question you'll see I have already done that.  The date stamp works great as a record separator.  My question was revolving around if it is possible for me to use that record separator as my stream reading token instead of - as the for-example - ReadLine.  The comments here have made it rather abundantly clear that there is no solution for this in the .NET framework.  I'm looking at the blog post linked in that question, but by its own admission it is messy and tends to lose its own message a lot.  I am unclear if it can help me at the moment.

Comment: Added code with @Blam suggested classes. I think this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all, you should move your const definition to class declaration - the compiler will do that for you, but this should be done by yourself, just for better code readability.

As @Blam mentioned, you should use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) and [StreamReader.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) in pair, something like this:

```
foreach(var filePath in logpath)
{
    var sbRecord = new StringBuilder();
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        do
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            // check start of the new record lines
            if (Regex.Match(line, datePattern) && sbRecord.Length > 0)
            {
                // your method for log record
                HandleRecord(sbRecord.ToString());
                sbRecord.Clear();
                sbRecord.AppendLine(line);
            }
            // if no lines were added or datePattern didn't hit
            // append info about current record
            else
            {
                sbRecord.AppendLine(line);
            }
        } while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    }
}
```

If I didn't understand something about your problem, please clarify this in comment.
Also, you can use [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza.aspx) for schedule the tasks for your lines, just for speed of your application.

Comment: I ended up coding my own solution that deals with the stream on a low-level basis, since I felt it was absolutely absurd that I couldn't parse a text stream a standardized token.  However, for basically anyone else this is more or less what you have to do.

Comment: @YYY May be you can provide your code here, just for the record? I think this would be interesting.

Comment: As much as I would love doing that, it is going to become part of some banking software soon and is therefore proprietary.  That said, when I get a few days off work one of the things on my agenda is to make an open source version and add it to my github, so I can expand the solution.  As it stands right now I basically read in a fixed number of bytes and keep a file position, which works great in the context of our project but isn't a good generalized solution.  That ambition will be continued once I duplicate/sanitize my initial work and add it to github.